# Java: how to handle a date with format like '2014-01-01T01:14:48.000+08:00'

Tags: java

I got a date `2014-01-01T01:14:48.000+08:00` from a web server. Does anyone know how to parse this correctly? How to get its `time offset`?

Comment: You mean parse? or format? or reformat? What is your expected output?

Comment: Use SimpleDateFormat to parse that Date and then use a Calendar to get the timeOffset

Comment: This type of format is called ISO 8601, google has plenty of answers...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: yes, parse this date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String s="2014-01-01T01:14:48.000+08:00";
         SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
         System.out.println(sdf.format(s));
```

Comment: I don't think this will work...

Comment: This doesn't work: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSX");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(y));
```

The `X` is for timezone.